# Trying to show a full years amount based on a smaller fraction of the year's total

Tags: excel, vba, math, excel-formula

this is my first post.

Right now, I have a limited set of data ranging from the beginning of this financial year until now. I'm trying to show what a full year's worth of that data would look like.

For example, if the number is at 10, and the data range is from 1/07/2021 - 30/12/2021 (half the year), then the end output should be 20. Or for example, turn a 12 with 3/4 of the year date range to 16 for a full years' worth.

However, my current formula would end up with 15 (10 + "half") rather than (10 + 10)

Right now this is what I have, but I know there's something off on my logic, as the output is smaller than it should be:

D1+((364-(F1-E1))/365)*D1

where E1 is the start date and F1 is the end date, and d1 is the number for that date range

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- `endDate - startDate` will give you the number of days the data covers.
- `(endDate - startDate) / 365` will give you what fraction of a year the sample represents.

Let’s say this works out to be 30%, or 0.30.

- `annualValue * 0.30 = periodValue` and therefore we know that `periodValue / 0.30 = annualValue`.

So there it is, the cell you want the Annual Value in should be:

`= periodValue / ( ( endDate - startDate) / 365 )`

I will leave it to you to replace each of the three named values in my example to be the correct cell references.  I suspect that’s probably:

`=D1/((F1-E1)/365)` which is the same as `(D1*365)/(F1-E1)`.

The easy way to remember this is that it’s just cross-multiplication.

periodValue / days is proportionate to annualValue / 365.  Thus `periodValue / days = annualValue / 365`. Cross-multiply and you get `periodValue * 365 = annualValue * days`. Divide both sides by days and you get `annualValue = (periodValue * 365)/days.